# How to check if data received from mongo database is empty?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, I'm trying to check if the data from my `.find()` is empty. I can check if it's null`, but I realize that when the .find() finds nothing, it returns an empty list. When I have an if statement saying

```
if (docs = []) {
// code here
} else {
// code here
}
```

It doesn't do the code and instead does the code if the documents got from the database. How can I make it check if it's an empty list?

Answer (score 0):

Check for length being 0 like `if(docs.length === 0)`

Comment: Have tried that already - still doesn't work. If it helps, the returned documents are in an array.

Comment: You should show why it did not work instead of telling it

Comment: Ah, sorry
          if (docs == null) {
                    // code
                } else if (docs.length === 0) {
                    // code
                } else { 
                   // code 

Even if the doc returns an empty array (returns []), it goes straight to the else instead of the else if.